# How to merge unit test outputs in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

My android project has many modules. I execute shell
`./gradlew test --continue`
to run unit test in all modules.
However , the result of each module is place in build dir of each module.

1.How to merge them in one file?

When I want a GUI of unit test , I right click the test dir of one module in android studio.It could run tests in only one module one time. It's very terrible because my project has about 20 modules.

2.Is there a way to run all unit tests in all modules one time?